# Curl equivalent of wget's --read-timeout=X

Tags: wget, curl

I'm trying to migrate my script from wget to curl.

```
wget -c --tries=0 --read-timeout=20 [URL]
```

What's the `curl` equivalent of this?

More specifically: what is the `curl` equivalent of `--read-timeout=X` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to a read timeout, but you might get a similar effect by setting a minimum speed limit, eg less than 1 byte/sec for 20 seconds:

```
--speed-limit 1 --speed-time 20
```

For infinite retries use `--retry 999` and to continue a download use `-C -`.